# How to reach into the classes which are inside an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

This is my code:

```
state = {
    classes: []
}

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/auth/booked/' + this.props.userId)
      .then(response => {
        const classes = response.data;
        const updatedClasses = classes.map(bookedClass => {
          return {
            ...bookedClass,
          }
        });
        this.setState({classes: updatedClasses});
        console.log(classes);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

With the above code I get this result:

[image: This is the array of objects I'm currently handling]

This is what I want to get:

[image: This is the objects I want to get]

So I want to dive deeper into the array of objects, I want to populate the `classes: []` with the information in the second image.

I have also tried this, which was adding `classID` on `const classes = response.data.classId;` at the end:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/auth/booked/' + this.props.userId)
      .then(response => {
        const classes = response.data.classId;
        const updatedClasses = classes.map(bookedClass => {
          return {
            ...bookedClass,
          }
        });
        this.setState({classes: updatedClasses});
        console.log(classes);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

But then I receive an error.
Any idea's in how I could access the object inside that array?

Comment: Both images look the same to me.  You just have one of the objects expanded in the second image.

Comment: If you look in the first Image, the first object is holding `classId`  that's the object I want to get, that's the expanded object in the second image. @Devon

Comment: No, the expanded object in the second image is at index 1 of the array, you may want to update it.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say but, how do I access if you look at image 1, the classId object? @Devon

Comment: In first attempt does changing to `updatedClass = classes.map(c=>{...c.classId})`  give expected result?

Comment: @barbsan So you mean changing it to this right? `const updatedClasses = classes.map(bookedClass => {
          return {
            ...bookedClass.classId
          }` If so it gave me the same result.

Comment: Did you refresh page? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQvQyg?editors=0011

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I'm getting the same result, I would have expected a different result. @barbsan

Comment: @Andrew `response.data.classId` does not exist.  `response.data[0].classId` and `response.data[1].classId` do.  It's an array, there isn't a single classId to select.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to learn. Let's see if I can get this working... @Devon

Comment: So Sorry, I was console.log(classes) instead of this.state.classes, so embarrassing, you answer did work. @barbsan

Answer (score 0):

You need to return in map's callback copy of each array element's `classId` property.

```
const classes = response.data;
const updatedClasses = classes.map(bookedClass => ({...bookedClass.classId}));
```